# Hive Create Permissions w/ Security Enabled

Tags: hadoop, hive

I've setup Kerberos as the security model for hive, but I'm struggling to get the permissions right.  Right now a user can create and drop a database fine, but can't create a table:

```
hive> show databases;
OK
cpenney
default
Time taken: 0.051 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive> drop database cpenney;
OK
Time taken: 0.098 seconds
hive> create database cpenney;
OK
Time taken: 0.062 seconds
hive> create table test ( hostgroup STRING );
Authorization failed:No privilege 'Create' found for outputs { database:cpenney}. Use show grant to get more details.
hive> show grant user cpenney on database cpenney;
OK
Time taken: 0.016 seconds
hive> grant all on database cpenney to user cpenney;
OK
Time taken: 0.022 seconds
hive> show grant user cpenney on database cpenney;
OK

database        cpenney
principalName   cpenney
principalType   USER
privilege       All
grantTime       Thu Sep 05 11:07:59 EDT 2013
grantor cpenney@REALM.COM
Time taken: 0.02 seconds, Fetched: 7 row(s)
hive> create table test ( hostgroup STRING );
Authorization failed:No privilege 'Create' found for outputs { database:cpenney}. Use show grant to get more details.
```

I'm using the following settings (some pruned from this paste):

```
<property>
  <name>hive.security.authorization.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.security.authorization.createtable.owner.grants</name>
  <value>ALL</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.security.metastore.authorization.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
 </property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.authorization.storage.checks</name>
  <value>true</value>
 </property>

<property>
  <name>hive.security.metastore.authorization.manager</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.DefaultHiveMetastoreAuthorizationProvider</value>
 </property>

<property>
  <name>hive.security.metastore.authenticator.manager</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.HadoopDefaultMetastoreAuthenticator</value>
</property>
```

It doesn't seem like the hive.security.authorization.createtable.owner.grants option is doing anything.  When I look in /user/hive/warehouse the file is owned by the same user so that seems right.

I'm using hadoop 1.1.1 and hive 0.11.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Set hive.security.authorization.enabled to FALSE

You can grant create to your user name.

for more details: [Hive Authorization](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Authorization)

Thanks,
SSP